# How to pass variable in jquery set date

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute some JS code using C#:

```
executor.ExecuteScript("window.document.getElementById('pmtDate').setAttribute('value','08/16/2013');");
```

Instead of `08/16/2013` I would like to pass variable for Date.

Can anyone please let me know the syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp_date='08/16/2013';

executor.ExecuteScript("window.document.getElementById('pmtDate').setAttribute('value',tempdate);");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right:

```
executor.ExecuteScript("var date = '08/16/2013'; window.document.getElementById('pmtDate').setAttribute('value',date);");
```

Comment: If i pass variable,below error occurs :System.InvalidOperationException : JavaScript error (UnexpectedJavaScriptError).

Comment: I am executing in visual studio and with C#. so not able to define it as function as mentioned answers as well..please guide me

Comment: See edits, I guess the initializing of the date has to be in the ExecuteScript aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
window.document.getElementById('pmtDate').setAttribute('value', getDate());


function getDate(){
    return currentDate.toString();
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekjain/Sfmh7/)

Updated Answer:

```
executor.ExecuteScript("function getDate(){return currentDate.toString();}var currentDate = new Date();window.document.getElementById('pmtDate').setAttribute('value', getDate());");
```

Comment: I am executing in visual studio and with C#. so not able to define it as function as mentioned answers as well..please guide me

Comment: Updated the answer please check

Answer (score 0):

My understanding, you want the date in mm/dd/yyyy format.
To get the current date, use the below code:

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();

var today = (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + d.getFullYear();
```

Now use this with your code.

```
executor.ExecuteScript("window.document.getElementById('pmtDate').setAttribute('value',"+today+");");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main techniques for doing this. One is string *concatenation*, the other is string *interpolation*.

### Concatenation

```
var theDate = "8/16/2013";    
var theCommand = "window.document.getElementById('pmtDate').setAttribute('value'," + theDate + ");"

executor.ExecuteScript(theCommand);
```

### Interpolation

```
var theDate = "8/16/2013";
var theCommand = String.Format("window.document.getElementById('pmtDate').setAttribute('value', {0});", theDate);

executor.ExecuteScript(theCommand);
```

If you're using [Selenium](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IJavaScriptExecutor_ExecuteScript.htm), you can also pass an argument array to the function:

```
var theDate = "8/16/2013";
var theCommand = "window.document.getElementById('pmtDate').setAttribute('value', arguments[0]);";

executor.ExecuteScript(theCommand, new object[] { theDate });
```

Comment: its giving some fractional value like 3.0565768e.